# Fancybox coding in Wordpress - link for images

Tags: php, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-3

i'm stumped. Firstly this is a Fancybox installed on theme, not a plugin, secondly - i'm still learning - so would super appreciate the help!

Fancybox needs a href link to open/load the images in wordpress post.

I am using "get attached media" to get all images on the post.

Where and how can I create the href link for Fancybox to work within this?

This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="img_div">

<?php $media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
if(! empty($media)){
foreach ( $media as $attachment ) {
    $full = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
    echo '<img class="image-2" data-fancybox="images" src="'.$full.'" alt="'$attachment->post_title'" />';
  }
 }
?>
</div>
```

And this this the Fancybox documentation:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="My caption">
<img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Any help would be amazing...i'm stumped on this part of the learning curve.

Comment: All items need the "fancybox" class and to get a rel="" which is the same for all images (so they get grouped together in the Fancybox when it loads), then it should work.

Comment: @Nathaniel Flic: No, v3 does not use "rel" for grouping. It uses value of "data-fancybox".

Comment: @Ideas_Emerging: What part is not clear for you? Just create links pointing to full image around thumbnail. Just like in the snippet (from documentation) you posted by yourself.

Comment: @janis thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Create links pointing to full size image, just like you see in the example:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="My caption">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

For example:

```
<div class="img_div">
<?php 

    $media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );

    if ( !empty($media) ) {
        foreach ( $media as $attachment ) {
            $full  = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );

            echo '<a data-fancybox="images" href="'.$full.'"><img class="image-2" src="'.$thumb .'" alt="'.$attachment->post_title.'" /></a>';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```